# What is the absolute maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=x^2-2x+2y$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the absolute maximum and minimum values of 
$$f(x,y)=x^2-2x+2y$$
on
$$d=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ 0 \le x \le 3, 0 \le y \le 2\}$$

Comment: It is not really two variable calculus, nor really calculus at all, our function is $(x-1)^2+2y-1$.

Answer (score 0):

As @André Nicolas pointed out in the comments, this function is just $(x-1)^2+2y-1$. Clearly, we need to find the maximum absolute value of $x-1$ and the maximum value of $y$. In this case, the maximum absolute value of $x-1$ is 2, by setting $x$ as 3, and the maximum value of $y$ is 2. Therefore, we have $2^2+2*2-1=4+4-1=7$.